# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' Next.js middleware

Tags: next.js

Next.js version: 13.4.7
Node.js version v18.16.0

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const accessToken = request.cookies.has('accessToken');
  const isLoginPage = request.nextUrl.pathname === '/login';

  if (!isLoginPage && !accessToken) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url));
  }
  return null;
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    '/',
    '/login',
    '/dashboard',
    '/dashboard/:path*',
    '/:path*/admin/:path*',
  ],
};
```

I also visited different forums stackoverflow,github but none of the solutions worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite

> /:path*/admin/:path*

to

> /admin/:path*